# How to make the first element of the list unchange in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, arraylist

Here is my list,

```
a = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l'],['m','n','o','p']]
```

and Here is my function,

```
def add(change,unchange):
    a = change
    b = unchange
    a[0].insert(a[0].index(a[0][2]),"high_range")
    a[0].insert(a[0].index(a[0][3]),"low_range")
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

When I try to execute this function,

```
add(a,a[0])
```

I'm getting this output,

```
[['a', 'b', 'high_range', 'low_range', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']]
['a', 'b', 'high_range', 'low_range', 'c', 'd']
```

But my expected output is the following,

```
[['a', 'b', 'high_range', 'low_range', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

How to make the first element of the list keep on same in the second variable ? Sorry I'm newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a list is a mutable type, when you insert values into `a` this also gets reflected in `b`, since they are pointers to the same list. You can either print `b` before inserting values into the list, or make `b` a copy of `unchange` like this:

```
def add(change,unchange):
    a = change
    b = unchange[:]
    a[0].insert(2, "high_range")
    a[0].insert(3, "low_range")
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Also, `a[0].index(a[0][2])` is redundant, you already know that the index is 2.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in line:

```
add(a, a[0])
```

as you are mutating `a` inside the function `a[0]` will change as well as they point to the same thing. You need to design your program accordingly. You can refer to this answer. [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

depending upon your requirement you can do this.

1. either suply a copy while calling a function.

`add(a, a[0][:])` # or

2. read @alec's answer.

Answer (score 1):

your function is perfect but execute this:

```
add(a,a[0][:])
```

this will make the second variable, namely `a[0]`, a copy, which will be left unchanged.